# [CSS]Dynamic image size and position in div with percent in percent. (Display-size)

Tags: css, image, dynamic, gallery

I am new here and I searched the web a couple of days and I have no idea how to solve the following problem.

My problem is, I want to do something which is similar to a image gallery. But the main problem is the dynamic size and position.

There are many people with different display resolutions. I got a netbook, so I got 1366x768, and other have for example 1024x600. So I want to make a gallery which looks on each resolution nice.

My first idea was creating a main container, which has a width of auto and same size on each resolution. Then an other div for a better structure, which are the images located.

The **HTML**:

```
<div id='content'>
    <div class='top-news'>
        <div class='slideshow'>
                     //images
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and the **CSS**:

```
#content{
height:auto;
width:auto;
background-color: #fff;
margin:20px 75px;
border:solid 1px #fff;
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.75); 
}

#content .top-news{
height:auto;
width:auto;
border-bottom:solid 1px #ddd;
}

#content .top-news .slideshow{
height:auto;
width:auto;
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 10px 10px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#content .slideshow img{
float:left;
width:211px;
height:125px;
border:solid 1px #aaa;
margin: 5px 5px;
}
```

So this looks pretty good on each display :)

Next idea was align the images so it looks pretty good (same space between div and images)...But I don't know how I can do this so its dynamic.

If I use pixels, it will be only look fine on same resolutions like me. The number of images in a row is not important. The main thing is the images should be in sequence and same spacing on each display.

I hope you can help me.

Cheers, hookiex3

Answer (score 0):

What gallery you need? Slide or fade? If slide-use JQ for calculate width. If you need fade - use width:100% and delete image size on your HTML.

Comment: Should be similar to http://pr0gramm.com/
There you can see that the Number of pics is dynamic for different display resolutions. I hope u know what i mean :D

Comment: you can use one of this JQ plugins: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ , http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope I will get it.:)